# Angular material datepicker md-date-locale directive not working

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-material

I'm trying to use the md-date-locale directive to overwrite angular material options for one date-picker input (as specified in https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdDatepicker) but it's not working.

Here is an example using the angular material example to test

```
md-date-locale="{ firstDayOfWeek: 2 }"
```

http://codepen.io/Hyperalpha/pen/gmwMdm

If it's not possible, I need to update datepicker options after loading (not in module.config() ).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set firstDayOfWeek in config function then its working fine

```
myAppModule.config(function($mdDateLocaleProvider) {
  $mdDateLocaleProvider.firstDayOfWeek = 2;
});
```

Working [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bqwwGv?editors=1010#0)

Comment: Thanks Gaurav but I want to update this parameter dynamically and I don't know if it's possible with the config function.

Comment: use $mdDateLocale service in controller for dynamic update, I have updated the [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bqwwGv?editors=1010#0), check now

Comment: It works ! I was using $mdDateLocaleProvider in my controller instead of $mdDateLocale to update dynamically this value (=> generate an error). With $mdDateLocale it works perfectly. Thanks Gaurav